# Why is mongodb aggregation $match not returning expected result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am building an aggregation pipeline. The following produce expected results individually or when run together:

```
let products = await Product.aggregate([
  { '$match': { brand: [Object] } },
  { '$match': { '$expr': [Object] } } ])
```

The following $match statement produces no data even though there is data in the collection that meets the criterion.

```
let products = await Product.aggregate([ { '$match': { rating: 4 } } ])
```

Sample data from collection:

```
{ _id: 5a295aef734d1d69e07ee6dd, rating: '4'},
{ _id: 5a296199734d1d69e07eec27, rating: '4'}
```

Comment: `[Object]` means ?

Comment: I'm willing to bet `'4' !== 4`

Comment: @Siva: { '$match': { brand: [$in: ['Amana' ]} }, console.log shows it as 'Object';

Comment: @RyanWheale I tested that with similar result: {$match: { rating: +rating} }

Comment: @RyanWheale You were right. My test was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mismatching data types.. you are sending an integer yet what is stored in the database is a string.. just add quotes :)